# Simple Jenkins pipeline file breaks in docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am running Jenkins on my OSX machine. My system was working fine last 2 weeks ago and I can't figure out what might have changed. I am running a super simple script to limit what I am doing to try to determine the problem but I am out of ideas. If anyone knows where to look next I would appreciate it. 
From what I can tell the docker command is running just fine. But the pipeline is breaking possibly when it is trying to enter the running docker container??? How can I confirm this and how can I see if there is a problem with my Jenkins, Docker, or system in general.

Here is the error:

```
Started by user userName
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /Users/userName/.jenkins/workspace/test2
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[test2] Running shell script
+ docker inspect -f . node:7-alpine
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:249)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:929)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:449)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:296)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:277)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:274)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.version(DockerClient.java:246)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.WithContainerStep$Execution.start(WithContainerStep.java:141)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:229)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:249)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:929)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:449)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:296)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:277)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:274)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.version(DockerClient.java:246)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.WithContainerStep$Execution.start(WithContainerStep.java:141)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:229)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(jar:file:/Users/lonnieramirez/.jenkins/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:135)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.node(jar:file:/Users/lonnieramirez/.jenkins/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:66)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(jar:file:/Users/lonnieramirez/.jenkins/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.DockerPipelineScript.runImage(jar:file:/Users/lonnieramirez/.jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/DockerPipelineScript.groovy:57)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.AbstractDockerPipelineScript.configureRegistry(jar:file:/Users/lonnieramirez/.jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/AbstractDockerPipelineScript.groovy:74)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.AbstractDockerPipelineScript.run(jar:file:/Users/lonnieramirez/.jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/AbstractDockerPipelineScript.groovy:52)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.CheckoutScript.checkoutAndRun(jar:file:/Users/lonnieramirez/.jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-extensions/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-extensions.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/CheckoutScript.groovy:66)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.CheckoutScript.doCheckout(jar:file:/Users/lonnieramirez/.jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-extensions/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-extensions.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/CheckoutScript.groovy:42)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.LabelScript.run(jar:file:/Users/lonnieramirez/.jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/LabelScript.groovy:44)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor83.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Here is my Jenkins file I got off the Jenkins website

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'node:7-alpine' }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Open a terminal, and get the docker version for us: `docker --version`

Answer (score 1):

Check your PATH when the Jenkins pipeline does execute itself, and see if you have installed Jenkins plugins recently.

For instance, [`palantir/gradle-docker` issue 162](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-docker/issues/162#issuecomment-377824293) mentions

> I'm also experiencing this and it seems to be because the `PATH` environment variable running under Gradle's Exec plugin (which this plugin uses to shell out to Docker) does not include `/usr/local/bin`.
>   In my case, I installed Docker using Homebrew which placed it there.

Check also [JENKINS-43294](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43294) regarding master and nodes:

> I've found that you can easily work around this bug by using the pipeline plugin, and using the `docker.image("some image").inside {}` function.
>   Just place that inside the proper `node('some label'){}` and it will run on the desired node.